# Discord.js send a medium post to a discord channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js, integration, medium.com-publishing-api

I would like to try send medium's post links into discord channel. However i didn't find much resources online. I found some SDK library but that really seems to be outdated `https://www.npmjs.com/package/medium-sdk`. It is possible to use Medium API somehow to send medium post from certain "user" as a medium post website link to the defined discord channel?
Not sure if someone ever did this. I only saw a posibility to create a medium post when a discord message is sent to the channel somehow. But that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you looking for how to have a Discord message sent when a Medium user posts a new article?

Comment: @user15517071
 Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package: [feed-watcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/feed-watcher), and set the feed to `https://medium.com/feed/@the_writer_name`.

Comment: Hello there! I tried to implement it, however i do not get any updates on new feed and i have weird error on startup ( i will receive some data only on startup of the script) `node test.js
Error: Invalid URI "rasmont.medium.com/feed?unit=second&interval=5"`

Comment: I have one problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69147878/discord-js-medium-integration-via-feed-watcher-cant-get-feed-link-from-the-upd . I don't know how to take data from the response so i can use them.

Answer (score 0):

This way, you can get medium posts from the feed-watcher and then send link from the medium post to the discord channel. (Feed is updating approx each 15-20 minutes.) So there might be a delay once medium post is posted to receive data from feed to send link to the channel.

```
'use strict';

//define your medium link in the feed
var Watcher = require('feed-watcher'),
feed = "https://yourmedium.medium.com/feed?unit=second&interval=5",
interval = 10 // seconds

var watcher = new Watcher(feed, interval)

// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const config = require("./configtest.json");

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.on('ready', () => {
  watcher.on('new entries', function (entries) {
    entries.forEach(function (entry) {
      const stringifylink = JSON.stringify(entry)
      const link = JSON.parse(stringifylink)
      console.log('FEED Call response:', link);
      console.log('Link:', link.link)
      //send new medium post link to the defined discord channel. 
      client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
      let channel = guild.channels.cache.get('ChannelID')
      channel.send('Check out our new medium post! ' + link.link)
      })
    })
  })
  watcher
  .start()
  .then(function (entries) {
    console.log(entries)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error)
  })
})

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(config.token);
```