# How to get a link from from feed-watcher updates

Tags: node.js, feed

I'm trying to build medium integration so when I new post arrives on medium, bot will then send the post link to the discord channel. The Problem is I don't know how to take data from the feed response so I can use it in the message. Once I receive the response from the feed, it looks like this.

```
{
    title: 'Hopefully will be done soon',
    description: '<p>Still making final testing!</p><img src="https://medium.com/_/stat?event=post.clientViewed&referrerSource=full_rss&postId=3d067e89b091" width="1" height="1" alt="">',
    summary: null,
    date: 2021-09-12T01:26:33.000Z,
    pubdate: 2021-09-12T01:26:33.000Z,
    pubDate: 2021-09-12T01:26:33.000Z,
    link: 'https://rasmont.medium.com/hopefully-will-be-done-soon-3d067e89b091?source=rss-762047c9bd39------2',
    guid: 'https://medium.com/p/3d067e89b091',
    author: 'RasmonT',
    comments: null,
    origlink: null,
    image: {},
    source: {},
    categories: [],
    enclosures: [],
    'rss:@': {},
    'rss:title': { '@': {}, '#': 'Hopefully will be done soon' },
    'rss:link': {
      '@': {},
      '#': 'https://rasmont.medium.com/hopefully-will-be-done-soon-3d067e89b091?source=rss-762047c9bd39------2'
    },
    'rss:guid': { '@': [Object], '#': 'https://medium.com/p/3d067e89b091' },
    'dc:creator': { '@': {}, '#': 'RasmonT' },
    'rss:pubdate': { '@': {}, '#': 'Sun, 12 Sep 2021 01:26:33 GMT' },
    'atom:updated': { '@': {}, '#': '2021-09-12T01:26:33.080Z' },
    'content:encoded': {
      '@': {},
      '#': '<p>Still making final testing!</p><img src="https://medium.com/_/stat?event=post.clientViewed&referrerSource=full_rss&postId=3d067e89b091" width="1" height="1" alt="">'
    },
    meta: {
      '#ns': [Array],
      '@': [Array],
      '#xml': [Object],
      '#type': 'rss',
      '#version': '2.0',
      title: 'Stories by RasmonT on Medium',
      description: 'Stories by RasmonT on Medium',
      date: 2021-09-12T01:39:23.000Z,
      pubdate: 2021-09-12T01:39:23.000Z,
      pubDate: 2021-09-12T01:39:23.000Z,
      link: 'https://medium.com/@rasmont?source=rss-762047c9bd39------2',
      xmlurl: 'https://medium.com/@rasmont/feed',
      xmlUrl: 'https://medium.com/@rasmont/feed',
      author: 'yourfriends@medium.com',
      language: null,
      favicon: null,
      copyright: null,
      generator: 'Medium',
      cloud: [Object],
      image: [Object],
      categories: [],
      'rss:@': {},
      'rss:title': [Object],
      'rss:description': [Object],
      'rss:link': [Object],
      'rss:image': [Object],
      'rss:generator': [Object],
      'rss:lastbuilddate': [Object],
      'atom:link': [Array],
      'rss:webmaster': [Object]
    }
  },
```

I tried to parse response so I can take the link from the response like this.

```
const link = JSON.parse(entry)
console.log('FEED Call response:', link["link"]);
```

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  watcher.on('new entries', function (entries) {
    entries.forEach(function (entry) {
      const link = JSON.parse(entry)
      console.log('FEED Call response:', link["link"]);
      console.log(entry)
    })
  })
  watcher
  .start()
  .then(function (entries) {
    console.log(entries)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error)
  })
})
```

Any idea how can I receive the data I want from the response so I can use it in the message?

Error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

I tried to use this, however I don't know how to get the link from the response.

```
const link = JSON.stringify(entries)
console.log('FEED Call response:', link);
console.log(`Link:`, link[0].link)
```

Reponse is `Link: [Function: link]`

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use `JSON.parse` at all! The received data is already the object you want. `JSON.parse` automatically sets its first argument as a string, and that makes it change to the following string:

```js
"[object Object]"
```

JSON allows the `[` but not the o without a quotation mark. The following code will work just fine.

```js
entries.forEach((entry) => {
      console.log('FEED Call response:', entry);
      console.log(entry[0].link)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution! First we need to stringify data and then parse them to JSON, right after i can pick link from the first array.

```
const stringifylink = JSON.stringify(entry)
  const link = JSON.parse(stringifylink)
  console.log('FEED Call response:', link);
  console.log('Link:', link[0].link)
```